# MYSQL add column of mark by numeric grades

Tags: mysql

Say I have a simple table of final grades:

```
Grades:
ID Grade
1   90
2   60
3   80
```

And I want to print a query of `ID`, `Grade`, and `mark` that will be calculated as A for 90+, B for 80+, C for 70+ and D for less, so in this example, the result will be:

```
ID Grade Mark
1  90    A
2  60    D
3  80    B
```

How will I do that?

Comment: Go on. Try something. If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry isn't that a minimal example?

Comment: Hint: Lookup `CASE` expressions.

Comment: It's not reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *,
       case
           when grade >= 90 then "A"
           when grade >= 80 then "B"
           when grade >= 70 then "C"
           else "D"
           end as Mark
from grades
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `CASE` in an example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f02a3/5

```
SELECT id, grade,
  CASE WHEN grade >= 90 THEN 'A'
       WHEN grade >= 80 THEN 'B'
       ELSE 'C'
  END AS Mark
FROM grades
```